# Multiple ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, render, jlist, listcellrenderer

Is it possible to have multiple ListCellRenderer's implementation in a single class?

Actually I have multiple JList's in my application and I would I am in need of different ListCellRenderer's for each.

Can I have different class names for Implementing ListCellRenderer's Component method.

For ex: If I have a class with name "MultiColumnCellRenderer" with some implementation of Component method and another class with name "MultiColumnCellRenderer2" with some other implementation of Component method?

```
public class MultiColumnCellRenderer extends JPanel implements
        ListCellRenderer {

    public MultiColumnCellRenderer() {
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

// Some implementation of Component Method

        super.setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        super.setFont(list.getFont());

        return this;
    }
}


public class MultiColumnCellRenderer2 extends JPanel implements
        ListCellRenderer {

    public MultiColumnCellRenderer2() {
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

// Some implementation of Component Method

        super.setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        super.setFont(list.getFont());

        return this;
    }
}`
```

And if I do something like:

```
list1.setCellRenderer(new MultiColumnCellRenderer());
list2.setCellRenderer(new MultiColumnCellRenderer2());
```

Its not working out....

I am looking for different rendering for both list1 and list2.

How can I achieve this

Comment: What is not working? Does the code not compile? Throw an exception at runtime? Or does the appearance just not look different between the two lists?

Comment: Hi Russell, thanks for quick reply..... Actually there are not any exceptions nor any compilation error.... But i believe the code under COMPONENT method is not getting executed.... Is it due to multiple implementation of COMPONENT method under different classes?

Comment: I actually checked it with debugger, instruction pointer is not moving inside body of COMPONENT method... though it does execute statements under "MultiColumnCellRenderer" or "MultiColumnCellRenderer2" class's constructor

Comment: PS... All implementation is under single JAVA file...

Comment: The code you have looks like it should work. I assume both lists actually have contents? If you have one of the renderers set its background to red and the other to blue, do both lists show up red? Or is one still the default color?

Comment: First, put only one Class per Java file. It's not stricly forbidden by the language, but should be considered as a bad practice

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW 1) The `MultiColumnCellRenderer` & `MultiColumnCellRenderer2` are identical in the `getListCellRendererComponent` method.  2) Add `@Override` notation to check the method name/signature is correct.

Comment: @RussellZahniser... instructions of first LISTCELLRENDERER is executing only.... i.e one list's color gets changed while other's is still default

Comment: @Grooveek.... I do prefer that too.. but if i create different class's then I wont be able to access variables of my parent class without creating it's object.... and I don't want constructor of my parent class to be called

Comment: @kartik mittal I same suggestion as (@Andrew Thompson), btw your logic must have some another issue, because there I can't see any reason why do not works ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to have multiple ListCellRenderer's implementation in a single class?

If by 'have' you mean 'use' and if by 'class' you mean 'GUI', then yes.

Here is an example:

[image: MultiColumnCellRendererTest]

### Source

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MultiColumnCellRendererTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String[] fruits = {
            "Apple",
            "Pear",
            "Banana",
            "Grapefruit"
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JList fruitList1 = new JList(fruits);
                fruitList1.setCellRenderer(new MultiColumnCellRenderer());

                JList fruitList2 = new JList(fruits);
                fruitList2.setCellRenderer(new MultiColumnCellRenderer2());

                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0,2,2));
                gui.add(fruitList1);
                gui.add(fruitList2);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MultiColumnCellRenderer extends JPanel implements
        ListCellRenderer {

    JLabel label;

    public MultiColumnCellRenderer() {
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        label.setText(value.toString());

        super.setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        super.setFont(list.getFont());

        return this;
    }
}


class MultiColumnCellRenderer2 extends JPanel implements
        ListCellRenderer {

    JLabel label;

    public MultiColumnCellRenderer2() {
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        label = new JLabel();
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        label.setText(value.toString());

        super.setEnabled(list.isEnabled());
        super.setFont(list.getFont());

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hiii... My code is very similar to the code you just posted.... but donno why its nt working out fr me.... :-(

Comment: Hello.... Thanks all for helping... The problem was in my logic only... CHEERS to StackOverflow and its VERY HELPFUL users... CHEERS

Answer (score 4):

Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that works - maybe you can figure out how this is different from your own code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
public class TwoLists {
    private static void list(ListCellRenderer renderer, Object... elements) {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        for(Object element : elements) {
            model.addElement(element);
        }

        JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setCellRenderer(renderer);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(list));
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                c.setBackground(Color.RED);
                return c;
            }
        }, "One", "Two", "Three");

        list(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
                    int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
                Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
                c.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                return c;
            }
        }, "North", "South", "EAST");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to arrange for a single `ListCellRenderer` implementation to manage a specified `Color`. In the variation below, a `darker()` color is used to signify selection.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987285 */
class MultiColumnCellRendererTest {

    private static final String[] fruits = {
        "Apple", "Pear", "Banana", "Grapefruit"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 2, 2));
                gui.add(createList(Color.red));
                gui.add(createList(Color.green));
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        });
    }

    private static JList createList(Color color) {
        JList list = new JList(fruits);
        list.setCellRenderer(new ColorCellRenderer(color));
        return list;
    }

    private static class ColorCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        private Color background;
        private Color selected;

        public ColorCellRenderer(Color background) {
            this.setOpaque(true);
            this.background = background;
            this.selected = background.darker();
            this.setBackground(background);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            setText(value.toString());
            setBackground(isSelected ? selected : background);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```